# Is there a flag to create a silent installer config for TwinCat 3

Tags: windows, installer, installshield

I want to install TwinCat 3 silently but there is no documented way to create a silent installer configuration file.

TwinCat 2 installer had the option to create an Install Shield configuration file (.iss) using the `-r` flag. That recorded the selected options first and then created a `.iss` file to run further setups with no user interaction.

In TwinCat 3 this option seems to be missing, but the help says, that you could do a silent installation by using a config file.

[image]

The question is, how to create (record) such a config file. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

TwinCat Setup V3.X is a MSI setup packed as EXE.
There is no need for a configuration file.
With a MSI setup you can specify installation switches on the command line.

We install Twincat silently with this command line:

```
setup.exe /s /clone_wait /v"/qr REBOOT=ReallySuppress ALLUSERS=1 INSTALLDIR=C:\TwinCat ACTIVATEVS2012SETTINGS=1"
```

To find the possible switches you can either use a MSI Viewer like "*Superorca*" and/or check the installation log file (after a manual installation).

Additionally we had to deal with windows security warnings (Do you trust this publisher ?)
This has been solved by installing the Beckhoff certificates first.